# How to check which roles are installed on a Windows Server 2003 with cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows, windows-command-prompt

If I log into a Windows Server 2003 and I want to check with cmd.exe which roles are installed, how to do that?

Comment: The concept of roles like in Server 2008Rx does not really exist in 2003. Are you talking about which 'Windows Components' are enabled? IIS would be a component, like AD is not part of the 'Windows Component Wizard', what exactly do you need to know?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf oops, ok i didn't know that, since i'm only used to ws 2008 r2. yes i'm looking for a list of what is called role in ws 2008 r2. in my case i wanted to see if the win 2003 server is running as a RADIUS server, i could check that by looking at the opened ports in netstat but there must be an easier way i think.. i prefered cmd.exe to look thinks up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of roles like in Server 2008Rx does not really exist in 2003. Extra features are know as 'Windows Components'.

The Windows 2003 implementation of a RADIUS server is called 'Internet Authentication Service', to find out whether this service is running open a command prompt and type:

```
net start | findstr /c:"Internet Authentication Service"
```

if the service is running, the command will output:

```
Internet Authentication Service
```

if not, it wont output anything.

If you are using a third party RADIUS server, find out the name of it and query for that.

```
net start
```

by itself gives all all the running services.

If the service is installed by not running, it is slightly more complicated:

Find out the internal name of the service, open

```
services.msc
```

Find the service in question, "Internet Authentication Service" and show the properties,
the General tab has the service name, in our case: 'IAS'

back on the command line type:

```
sc query IAS
```

if it is installed you should see something like this:

```
SERVICE_NAME: IAS
    TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

If it is not installed, you'll get an error:

```
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

If the 'role' you are looking for is not using a Windows Service, than you have to look elsewhere. You can get a list of installed software using a script with WMI.

Or you can use [PsInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550):

```
psinfo.exe -i
```

to list all installed software, then again you can use findstr too look for the
software you are after.