# Get a list of installed optional features on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

In Win7+ i can run the following command to get a list of optional features:

```
wmic path Win32_OptionalFeature get Caption,InstallState
```

How can i get a similar list on WinXP, natively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole concept of "optional features" which can be installed and uninstalled was introduced with Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008; it was not present in earlier systems.

Oh, and it's much easier to get a list of installed features using PowerShell:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online
```

Or using `dism`:

```
dism.exe /Online /Get-Features
```

---

The same question has been asked several times about Windows Server 2003 (XP's server counterpart), but it has no definite answer other than "try to guess what is installed from available services and Registry keys"; see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/355791/how-to-check-which-roles-are-installed-on-a-windows-server-2003-with-cmd-exe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902380/windowsserver-2003-cmd-check-installed-roles).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Massimo, and for pointing similar questions.